# Does React state get saved before setting it with useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Sorry for the confusing question. First I will like to share my code:

```
  const intialState = {
    output: null,
    bookIdToDelete: null
  }
  const [state,setState] = useState(intialState)

  useEffect(() => {
    getDataFromServer().then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      if (data != 2) {
        // job gonna be here
        const output = data.map(book => {
          return (
            <div key={book._id} className="col-md-3">
              <div className="item">
                <img className="bookimage" src={book.imgs[0]} alt="img"/>
                <h3>
                  <Link to={"/admin/mybook/" + book._id}>{book.title}</Link>
                </h3>
                <h6>
                  <Link to={"/admin/mybook/" + book._id}>Edit</Link>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <button id={book._id} onClick={deleteBtnClick} className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </h6>
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })
        setState({...state, output})
      }
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }, [])


  const deleteBtnClick = (e) => {
    let bookId = e.target.id;
    console.log(state)
    setState({
        ...state,
        bookIdToDelete: bookId
     })
  }
  


console.log('showmodal',state);
  return (
    <>

       {state.output}

    </>
  )
}

export default MyBooks
```

Basically what this does is that I obtain an array with some information and create a list using a map. I do this all inside the useEffect. Every item has a delete button that calls another function that just saves the id of the element that I want to delete inside the state. What is happening is that when I click on this delete button the state is always equal to the initial state and not with the one I updated in the useEffect. It seems that as I created the array of elements inside the useEffect before I set the state to the its new value the state that is used in the "deleteBtnClick" function is the old one, in this case the initial one....

So I solved this by just saving the information in the useEffect and then creating the list with the map before the return of the component... But I still have the doubt of why it was happening... so if you know why I will appreciate the explanation. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are right. If you save the elements in your state, they will refer to the `deleteBtnClick` function that existed at the moment `useEffect` ran (first render of the component), which in turn will refer to the state that existed at that point in time. I think only storing the data in state and rendering the elements outside of it makes more sense. However, also know that you can pass a callback to `setState` to receive the "current" value of the state.

Comment: @FelixKling Hey thanks for the answer. I didn't think about using the callback in the `setState` , although I think I will use the approach of rendering outside of the `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

in general I would organize my code like this:

```
const intialState = {
    output: [],
    bookIdToDelete: null
  }
  const [state,setState] = useState(intialState)

  useEffect(() => {
    getDataFromServer().then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      if (data != 2) {
        // job gonna be here
        const output = data
        setState({...state, output})
      }
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }, [])


  const deleteBtnClick = (e) => {
    let bookId = e.target.id;
    console.log(state)
    setState({
        ...state,
        bookIdToDelete: bookId
     })
  }          
  return (
    <>

       {state.output.map(book => {
          return (
            <div key={book._id} className="col-md-3">
              <div className="item">
                <img className="bookimage" src={book.imgs[0]} alt="img"/>
                <h3>
                  <Link to={"/admin/mybook/" + book._id}>{book.title}</Link>
                </h3>
                <h6>
                  <Link to={"/admin/mybook/" + book._id}>Edit</Link>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <button id={book._id} onClick={deleteBtnClick} className="btn btn-    danger">Delete</button>
                </h6>
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })}

    </>
  )
}

export default MyBooks
```